# PHP SnapChat Master - Correct log in credentials returning invalid log in

Tags: php, html, snapchat

I am trying to use the third party SnapChat API from [this](https://github.com/JorgenPhi/php-snapchat) repository.

Here is the PHP code that I am running.

```
<?php

/* TODO - Debug show errors */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Start or continue the session
session_start();
// Require the php-snapchat-master api
require_once("../api/snapchat.php");
// If the user is logged in
if (isset($_SESSION["username"]) && isset($_SESSION["password"])) {
  // Redirect to the home page
  header("Location: ../home/");
}
// If the username and password are not set
else {
  // Break PHP to show HTML
  ?>
  <form method="POST">
    <input type="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
  </form>
  <?php // End PHP break
  // If the log in form was submitted
  if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
    // Initialize the prospective user
    $snapchat = new Snapchat();
    // If the username and password are not valid
    if ($snapchat->login($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]) == FALSE) {
      // ECHO INVALID
      echo "INVALID";
    }
    // If the username and password are valid
    else {
      // ECHO VALID
      echo "VALID";
      // Set the username session variable
      $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
      // Set the password session variable
      $_SESSION["password"] = $_POST["password"];
      // Redirect to the home page
      header("Location: ../home/");
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Unfortunately, every time I enter in my correct username and password for SnapChat, the page will display my debug `INVALID` statement. I am not sure why this happens, when I add in an always true check for a login (Such as if (TRUE == TRUE)), then it works perfectly fine.

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the guys at Snapchat changed their API yet another time to defend against rogue clients even though it's technically impossible and they should accept that; if it's urgent you can MITM the app yourself and fix the library; otherwise just wait for someone else to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login method of Snapchat has changed :/ So this API need an update. Don't worry about your code, it's OK ;)

**EDIT** : Found !

You must modify User Agent used by this "API" :
Go to snapchat_agent.php and modify the $CURL_OPTIONS like that :

```
public static $CURL_OPTIONS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Snapchat/8.1.1 (Nexus 5; Android 21; gzip)',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Accept-Language: en'),
);
```

Comment: After the discover update, 'Snapchat/8.1.1' ^  needs to be changed to 'Snapchat/9.0.1'